# Can i install a receptacle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

im wanting to install a receptacle in my living room, im no expert but im always willing to learn. there are white, red and black wires. could you help me with this project. i would greatly appreciate it. also, should i install a regular receptacle or a GFIC one. thanks[image]

Comment: What used to be installed in the junction box?

Comment: sorry, i dont know. the house was built in the 30s, but i just bought it

Comment: How did the wires get there? What was there before? What else is currently on that circuit? Is that at chest level or closer to where you'd expect a receptacle? Is there another outlet nearby? You may wish to check how it's wired. The red wire indicates a potential traveler for a 2 or 3 way switch.

Comment: At minimum you'll need a non-contact voltage tester to figure out which wires are hot. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-Non-Contact-Voltage-Tester-NCVT-1SEN/100661787

Comment: I see no ground wire so you should get a GFCI receptacle for it or better yet, install an AFCI breaker for that circuit.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I didn't see grounds at first, either, but they're there  on the right, conveniently spray painted by lazy painters who couldn't be bothered to mask off the box. (I think - they've got a hint of brown/copper color, but then, there's a stripe of a very similar color on top of the red wire on the left side of the box.)

Comment: thanks for the answers. so how would i wire this to a GFCI receptacle

Comment: @FreeMan I see it now, assuming that's not just old overspray. Given the fact that it's twisted with presumably a neutral I have little hope for any of this to be simple. Luis, this is not a good learning opportunity for someone who has never done electrical. I admire your enthusiasm but it's impossible for anyone here to provide guidance unless you can figure out which wires are hot. I really recommend an electrician. If they're worth their salt then they should be able to figure this out fairly quickly.

Comment: Can you tell me which wire nut the white wire from the right-hand cable goes into? I can't tell based on your photo...